# setting number to a clicked item of android gridview

Tags: android, gridview

I am new to android programming. this question might be easy but I could not get a soln.
I want to set an empty gridview and set a number starting from 1 and increasing when clicked at any item of the gridview.
I can set the gridview but could not set a number into clicked item. can anyone help? Thanks... 
here is the code;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
GridView grid;

String[] numbers = new String[] { "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,numbers);

    grid.setAdapter(adapter);

    grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    numbers[position]="1";                              
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: [Refreshing GridView in Android](https://www.google.com/search?q=refreshing+GridView+in+Android&oq=refreshing+GridView+in+Android&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.10735j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0):

If you are modifying an underlying data store of an `Adapter`, to reflect the changes in the UI, the [`notifyDataSetChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) method needs to be invoked.